# No Numbers Sudoku: The Ball of Queens

Tags: grid-deduction, chess, sudoku

[image: Sudoku Grid]

Those are all of the numbers you need. No, I did not forget any.

- Normal sudoku rules apply.
- All numbers, except for 1's and 9's, are queens with respect to themselves.

  - E.g. 2's have the queen's constraint against other 2's but not against 3's.
- All numbers must be rotationally symmetric with respect to their counter part on the other side of 5.

  - Aka, 1 with 9, 2 with 8, 3 with 7, 4 with 6, and 5 with itself. See below image for an example.
- Not all 2's are next to non-queens in the top three sudoku squares. Aka, the white sudoku squares in the image below.
- All 2's must be next to a 4 in the three middle sudoku squares. Aka, the three blue sudoku squares in the image below.
- All 2's must be next to a 3 in the three bottom sudoku squares. Aka, the three red sudoku squares in the image below.
- If a 2 is surrounded by 3 non-queens, it will see two 9's.
- Top right corner is not a queen.
- The queens of 5 dance clockwise.

[image]

"Next to" includes above, below, to the side, or diagonally.

This is my first sudoku puzzle, so any feedback would be awesome. Good luck!

**EDIT** Apologies, I noticed another symmetry within the puzzle that needed defining to gift a unique solution. I've added 1 last rule at the bottom to account for this.

**HINTS**

> r1c3, r2c9, r3c4, r4c8, r5c5

Comment: Is "next to" also diagonally?

Comment: Yes, I'll amend the description to be a bit clearer. Thanks.

Comment: And "rotationally symmetric" means "at a multiple of 45 degrees within each 3x3 box", correct?

Comment: No, it means the entire sudoku grid could be rotated and the numbers would fall onto their counterparts perfectly. According to Wikipedia its "Automorphic", but I wasn't sure about using jargon ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Automorphic_Sudokus )

Comment: So rotationally symmetric means a 2-fold symmetry (180 degrees), not a 4-fold (90 degrees) symmetry. What do you mean by "dance clockwise"?

Comment: 2-fold symmetry (180 degrees) is correct, yes. Rot13(Bs gur znal fbyhgvbaf sbe cynpvat gur dhrraf bs svir qbja, gur pbeerpg inevnag znxrf gurz nccrne gb or fcvaavat pybpxjvfr.)

Comment: Hmm. Of the 8 possible configurations of 5's, I don't see one more "spinning clockwise" than another.

Comment: @Jens Rot13(vir nqqrq n uvag gb pyrne guvatf hc. vf gurer n orggre jnl sbe qrfpevovat vg orfvqrf fcvaavat pybpxjvfr? v fnj vg nf yvxr fgevat orvat fcha nebhaq n prager juvpu yrq gb gur qrfpevcgvba. nz bcra gb vqrnf gubhtu)

Comment: Your hint makes it very clear :)

Comment: @Jens ideally the hint shouldn't be needed as, without the 5 queens dance clockwise clue, there are only 2 possible solutions :p That's why i was wondering if there's a better way to give the clue.

Comment: OK, but 2 is still more than 1. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113282/discussion-between-user3303504-and-jens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a program to solve this. I found 15 solutions. Here are two of them. As the solution should be unique, I tried to hunt for violation of the rules. But I could not found any.

> ```
>   8  9  5 |  6  7  2 |  3  4  1
>   1  7  2 |  3  4  8 |  6  9  5
>   3  4  6 |  5  9  1 |  2  7  8
> ----------+----------+---------
>   7  2  3 |  1  8  6 |  9  5  4
>   4  8  9 |  7  5  3 |  1  2  6
>   6  5  1 |  4  2  9 |  7  8  3
> ----------+----------+---------
>   2  3  8 |  9  1  5 |  4  6  7
>   5  1  4 |  2  6  7 |  8  3  9
>   9  6  7 |  8  3  4 |  5  1  2
>
>
>   6  1  5 |  3  2  4 |  8  7  9
>   9  2  4 |  8  7  6 |  3  1  5
>   8  7  3 |  5  1  9 |  4  2  6
> ----------+----------+---------
>   2  4  8 |  9  6  3 |  1  5  7
>   7  6  1 |  2  5  8 |  9  4  3
>   3  5  9 |  7  4  1 |  2  6  8
> ----------+----------+---------
>   4  8  6 |  1  9  5 |  7  3  2
>   5  9  7 |  4  3  2 |  6  8  1
>   1  3  2 |  6  8  7 |  5  9  4
> ```

Comment: "All numbers must be rotationally symmetric with respect to their counter part on the other side of 5." on the first line of your first solution you have "8 9 5 6 7" but 8 is not the counterpart of 7 and 9 is not the counterpart of 6.

Comment: @Stef this is not how I read that condition. I though it meant that the top-left 8 has their counterpart in the bottom-right 2 etc

Comment: @daw okay, you put my programming skills to shame! I thought I had checked all possibilities as well but clearly not. FYI, the first sudoku you put up was the intended solution.